# Attempting to reproduce MS Word styling in CSS

Tags: css, ms-word, epub

I'm attempting to recreate the attached style from MS Word in CSS to use in an ePUB I'm working on for a friend.  I can always take a screenshot of each chapter heading and do it that way, but I'd prefer that it be done in CSS.

Here's what I've got in Word:

[image]

[image]

Here is the code I have so far:

```
@font-face {
    font-family : "AR Christy";
    font-style : normal;
    font-weight : normal;
    src : url("../fonts/archristy.ttf");
}
h1 {
    font-family : "AR Christy", serif;
    font-weight : bold;
    font-style : normal;
    font-size : 30pt;
    text-decoration : none;
    font-variant : normal;
    color : #95B932;
   -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
   -webkit-text-stroke-color: white;
   -webkit-text-stroke: 1px white;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888888;
    line-height : 1;

}
```

And here's how it looks when rendered in Safari:
[image]

I seem to be having trouble with the "texture" of the text, if that makes sense.

The font is available here if you're interested in trying to help:
http://fontzone.net/font-details/ar-christy

I've added the following two closeup pictures to make the difference more obvious.  Here's the Word version:

[image]

And here's the current CSS version:

[image]

EDIT: Thanks to Kelly's suggestion, I decided that I had to use multiple shadow layers.  This is the code I ended up using:

```
text-shadow: rgb(187, 187, 187) 0px 1px 0px,
  rgb(181, 181, 181) 0px 2px 0px,
  rgb(172, 172, 172) 0px 3px 0px,
  rgb(160, 160, 160) 0px 4px 0px,
  rgb(145, 145, 145) 0px 5px 0px,
  rgb(127, 127, 127) 0px 6px 0px,
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.199219) 0px 7px 1px,
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.296875) 0px 8px 6px;
```

Which looks like this... Not exactly a match, but I like the overall feel:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The end result is that nothing would mimic Word's styling exactly.  I attempted to use the code mentioned to create an inner shadow, but it didn't work with the font I was using.

I ended up going with a different 3d effect, that was achieved by layering multiple shadows.  Here's the shadow code I used, along with the final text:

```
text-shadow: rgb(187, 187, 187) 0px 1px 0px,
  rgb(181, 181, 181) 0px 2px 0px,
  rgb(172, 172, 172) 0px 3px 0px,
  rgb(160, 160, 160) 0px 4px 0px,
  rgb(145, 145, 145) 0px 5px 0px,
  rgb(127, 127, 127) 0px 6px 0px,
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.199219) 0px 7px 1px,
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.296875) 0px 8px 6px;
```

[image]

I gave Kelly credit for sending me down the right path with multiple layers.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing shadow only, not texture difference..

just add this line and you will see similar result..

```
 -webkit-text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888888;
```

Edit,

with the shadow effect, modify this(as you don't want -webkit-)

```
text-shadow:2px 4px 6px RGBA(0,0,0,0.7);
```

Now you want tyhe 3d effect in font that is possible using inset shadow,
check the fiddle I have created that have 2 text one have shadow, and another have inset shadow, that creates look a like effect.. although its not the same as word 3d,
[`FIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/m6HDs/1/)

I hope this will help.

Comment: I've already got text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888888;  Adding the webkit version of the same thing makes no difference.

Comment: @Lawson How about something like this: `text-shadow: 0px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.8)`
If you need more blur, adjust the third argument (The 10px).
If you need a darker colour, increase the alpha (the 0.8).

Comment: how ever I have to say, I have provided half, layers are not the same you were looking but if it satisfy your need that's great,FYI Still internal(inset) shadow is missing... in accepted answer..

Answer (score 0):

It will be hard to exactly mimic that inner-shadow effect as the illusion of 'pillow embossed' (as in the photoshop effect) isn't an evenly distributed effect. AFAIK, css effects are all behind an object so you would need to get into placing one version above another to get it close.

Comment: I'm going to award you the points for giving me the idea to layer multiple shadows.  I ended up going with this:  text-shadow: rgb(187, 187, 187) 0px 1px 0px,
  rgb(181, 181, 181) 0px 2px 0px,
  rgb(172, 172, 172) 0px 3px 0px,
  rgb(160, 160, 160) 0px 4px 0px,
  rgb(145, 145, 145) 0px 5px 0px,
  rgb(127, 127, 127) 0px 6px 0px,
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.199219) 0px 7px 1px,
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.296875) 0px 8px 6px;